Movie about a man with super healing powers
Because I was younger I'm not entirely sure when I actually even watched the film, but I estimate between 2010-2014. I'm quite sure it was not an 80s or 90s movie - maybe very late 90s, but more likely to be from the 2000s.
I remember only about three things from the film:

The main character is almost like a vigilante/superhero who gains super healing when he gets into an accident and gets exposed to chemicals.
I think the big truck said something dumb like "gamma" or something to that degree. It was red, so I just remember a lot of red stuff all over the screen.
The last thing I remember is how near the end of the film there is a scene, after the protagonist gets blown up or disintegrated, and his finger is laying there with blood leaking out and it just slowly starts flowing back in. I think this was because someone thought they could kill him by leaving him with nothing left to heal, but he just comes back to life, I guess.

That's about all I can remember, and it has been bothering me for almost a decade.

This is  The Spirit (2008).
Per TV Tropes,

At the end of The Spirit, it is implied that the Octopus, who has just been blown up all over an alleyway, will be able to regrow himself from a single finger.





IT REALLY IS THIS MOVIE!! It's insane that someone replied so fast I was expecting radio silence for a year but I could tell immediately from the lighting that it is this film. I checked letterboxd now and the ratings and so low it's sad but that isn't gonna stop me from watching it so thank you. Time to ruin my childhood.

Eh, in my opinion, the film was entertaining in the same way that Starship Troopers or the 1960s Batman TV show are, namely that they take the initial premise and treat with a great deal of camp. Is it a great work? No. Is it fun to watch? I thought so.

Starman (1984) with Jeff Bridges.

